# format an excel column to accept date in particular format only phpExcel

Tags: php, excel, date, phpexcel, cell-formatting

I am generating an excel sheet via phpExcel in which dates are retrieved in 01-JAN-1900 format.But I want it to be visible in DD-MM-YYYY format right from when the excel sheet is generated with default date values fetched from DB.Also the date format is DD-MM-YYYY in DB.So how can we format that cell to display the date in that particular format.
I am using this code.Then too,the DB fetched dates values are in 01-JAN-1900 format only. Please help.

```
        for($i=2;$i<$count;$i++){
         $objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
        ->getStyle('V'.$i)
        ->getNumberFormat()
        ->setFormatCode(
            PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_DDMMYYYY
        );
```

Comment: It isn't important what the date looks like as it gets put into the cell as a value. Today happens to be 42,352. What matters is that the cell has a display format of `dd-mm-yyyy` so that it will look like `14-12-2015` in the worksheet cell. Of equal importance is that `11-12-2015` does not become `12-Nov-2015` when a DMY is interpreted by the very EN-US-centric VBA as MDY.

Comment: You need to ensure that you correctly set the cell value to an MS Serialize datetime stamp..... then you can use the format mask to show how it should be displayed..... how are you setting the cell value?